# Sling servlet returns 404 after migration cq 6.0 --> 6.1 SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Resource not found

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

After migration 6.0 --> 6.1

url

```
localhost:4502/services/reference?op=get-all
```

become respond 404 http code.

on 6.0 it returns json and 200 http status.

Actually in code it treatment to sling servlet:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@SlingServlet(
        paths = {"/services/reference"},
        methods = {"GET"},
        name = "www")
public class MyServlet extends AbstractBaseServlet {

    ...
    @Reference
    private TagAdminService tagAdminService;


    @Override
    protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest req, final SlingHttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ...               

    }

}


public abstract class AbstractBaseServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {...}
```

errors in log:

```
16.07.2015 14:08:36.063 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1437041316060] GET /services/reference HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Resource /services/reference not found
16.07.2015 14:08:36.064 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1437041316060] GET /services/reference HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver Calling the error handler resulted in an error
org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp(10,4) The value for the useBean class attribute com.ctc.aem.site.apps.sling.servlet.errorhandler.JsonErrorCustomizer is invalid.
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:762)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:442)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.DefaultErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl$1.render(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:345)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.handleError(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:167)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:217)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:336)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp(10,4) The value for the useBean class attribute com.ctc.aem.site.apps.sling.servlet.errorhandler.JsonErrorCustomizer is invalid.
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1213)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1155)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2351)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2401)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2407)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:489)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2351)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3402)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:210)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:310)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:290)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:501)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.prepareServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:427)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:486)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
16.07.2015 14:08:36.065 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1437041316060] GET /services/reference HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver Original error null
16.07.2015 14:08:36.065 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1437041316060] GET /services/reference HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.DefaultErrorHandler Error handler failed:java.io.IOException
java.io.IOException: Error handler failed: org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:771)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:442)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.DefaultErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl$1.render(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:345)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.handleError(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:167)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:217)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:336)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp(10,4) The value for the useBean class attribute com.ctc.aem.site.apps.sling.servlet.errorhandler.JsonErrorCustomizer is invalid.
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:762)
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp(10,4) The value for the useBean class attribute com.ctc.aem.site.apps.sling.servlet.errorhandler.JsonErrorCustomizer is invalid.
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1213)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1155)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2351)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2401)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2407)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:489)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2351)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3402)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:210)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:310)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:290)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:501)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.prepareServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:427)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:486)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

What can be wrong?

How to fix it?

Comment: make sure you've not reconfigured your 'Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler' component. It specifies all allowed servlet paths. Moreover, try calling the servlet with a proper extension e.g. `/services/reference.json?op=get-all`

Comment: Sorry, stupid question. It was related with bundle cannot resolve dependency and thus became not active.  I changed poi library version to 2.0.0 and it became work.